# create html elements in a factory in angular.js

Tags: angularjs

I have a css that helps me to generate a preloader or a loading animation. The only thing I lack is the html code. My idea is to create a factory that allows to create the html code necessary for the preloader to be generated. Can you please give me an example or say how to do it ?.

thank you very much.

Comment: i think you would want is a directive.

Comment: how? and why???

Comment: theres tutorials online. a directive encapsulates the logic of a reusable piece of html.

Comment: @DanielA.White I do not know much about angular, but my functions and others, I call them from a factory.

Answer (score 0):

This can be effectively achieved using **AngularJS 1.5's** [Components](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component)
The code creates a `<menu-bar>` component which spits out `bootstrap <nav-bar>` in the template.

```js
//-- app.module.js --//
var app = angular.module('app', []);

//-- app.menu-bar.component.js --//
app.component('menuBar', {
  bindings: {
    brand: '@'
  },
  templateUrl: '/partials/menuBar.html',
  controller: function() {
    this.menu = [{
      name: "Home",
    }, {
      name: "About",
    }, {
      name: "Contact",
    }];
  }
});
```

```html
<!-- /partials/menuBar.html -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">{{$ctrl.brand}}</a>
    </div>
    <div>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li ng-repeat="menu in $ctrl.menu">
          <a href="#">{{menu.name}}
        </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
<!-- End of menuBar.html -->

<!-- index.html -->
<html en="us" ng-app='app'>

<head>
  <title>
    NavBar with Angular 1.5.x components
  </title>
  <!-- bootsrap css-->
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <!-- angularjs-->
  <script src="lib/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
  <!-- The main app script-->
  <script src="js/app.module.js"></script>
  <script src="js/components/app.navbar.component.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <menu-bar brand='abc'></menu-bar>
</body>


</html>
```